# How to add <script> tag in HTML2pdf

Tags: php, html2pdf

Any idea how to include `<SCRIPT>` tags in HTML2PDF.I have a clean HTML page to converted into PDF but it tells `<script>` tag not supports.So,please help me how to include this tag in class file.

```
Uncaught File : /opt/lampp/htdocs/hari/pdf2/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php
Line : 1252
```

The tag **<SCRIPT>** does not yet exist.
If you want to add it, you must create the methods **o_SCRIPT** (for opening) and **c_SCRIPT** (for closure) by following the model of existing tags.
If you create these methods, do not hesitate to send me an email to webmaster@html2pdf.fr to included them in the next version of HTML2PDF. thrown in `/opt/lampp/htdocs/hari/pdf2/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php` on line 1252

Comment: It sounds like the author of that library has not yet implemented it.  That error message tells you what you would need to implement to get it working and that the author would appreciate code contributions if you do get it working.  Maybe you should check that you have the latest version of the library and look at the project's change log before diving into the code.

Comment: Thank you,Mike.I'll check it out

Answer (score 4):

In V4.03, you can add these methods (the error message give bad methods names...) to generate the pdf but the content of SCRIPT tags won't be taken in account :

```php
protected function _tag_open_SCRIPT($param)
{
    return false ; // or return true, same behaviour
}

protected function _tag_close_SCRIPT($param)
{
    return false ;
}
```

You will be able to generate your pdf, as if the SCRIPT tag were not in your doc...

Answer (score 2):

[HTML2PDF's change log](http://html2pdf.fr/en/download) says

- v3.17
  add possibility to save the scripts in pdf, via $ html2pdf-> pdf-> IncludeJS (...); (see examples JS)

Comment: Problem is below script doesn't get accepted <body>  
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
  var chart;
  $(document).ready(function() {
   chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
     renderTo: '144',
     plotBackgroundColor: null,
     plotBorderWidth: null,
     plotShadow: false
    }, 
   });
  });
 });
 </script> 
<div name="144" id="144" style="min-width: auto; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div><br /> 
</body>

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that complex Javascript effects, like jQuery and Highcharts, will work in a PDF. In this, you are mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

In parsingHtml.class.php you must include one line in this function:

```
public function setHTML($html)
{
    // remove the HTML in comment
    $html = preg_replace('/<!--(.*)-->/isU', '', $html);
    // remove the HTML in script
    $html = preg_replace('/<script>(.*)<\/script>/isU', '', $html); // Include this line

    // save the HTML code
    $this->_html = $html;
}
```